# Python Triangular Arbitrage Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, bellman-ford

I am looking to create a Python based triangular arbitrage algorithm. All the resources I have looked at are all connected to Coin Exchanges on Binace etc. I am just looking for an "engine" where as I can simply provide the Matrix Table (or any other option would be appreciated)

I was working on a code I took off stackoverflow (as per below)

```
    from typing import Tuple, List
    from math import log

    '''
    rates = [
        [1, 0.23, 0.26, 17.41],
        [4.31, 1, 1.14, 75.01],
        [3.79, 0.88, 1, 65.93],
        [0.057, 0.013, 0.015, 1],
    '''

    rates = [
        [1,2363.353782,1492.716318,7844.449626,10.980451,75149.558747],
        [0.00042,1,0.634884,3.309109,0.004684,32.1756],
        [0.0006,1.5656,1,5.2004,0.007319,50.117612],
        [0.000126,0.300385,0.191139,1,0.001401,9.603383],
        [0.0897,211.9355,135.762445,706.204,1,6785.758382],
        [0.0000001,0.0308,0.019833,0.1035,0.000146,1],
    ]

    currencies = ('YFIN', 'YFLR','xUSD','FXRP','FLTC','FDOGE')

    #currencies = ('PLN', 'EUR', 'USD', 'RUB')


    def negate_logarithm_convertor(graph: Tuple[Tuple[float]]) -> List[List[float]]:
        ''' log of each rate in graph and negate it'''
        result = [[-log(edge) for edge in row] for row in graph]
        return result


    def arbitrage(currency_tuple: tuple, rates_matrix: Tuple[Tuple[float, ...]]):
        ''' Calculates arbitrage situations and prints out the details of this calculations'''

        trans_graph = negate_logarithm_convertor(rates_matrix)

        # Pick any source vertex -- we can run Bellman-Ford from any vertex and get the right result

        source = 0
        n = len(trans_graph)
        min_dist = [float('inf')] * n
        
        min_dist[source] = source

        # 'Relax edges |V-1| times'
        for _ in range(n-1):
            for source_curr in range(n):
                for dest_curr in range(n):
                    if min_dist[dest_curr] > min_dist[source_curr] + trans_graph[source_curr][dest_curr]:
                        min_dist[dest_curr] = min_dist[source_curr] + trans_graph[source_curr][dest_curr]

        # if we can still relax edges, then we have a negative cycle
        for source_curr in range(n):
            for dest_curr in range(n):
                if min_dist[dest_curr] > min_dist[source_curr] + trans_graph[source_curr][dest_curr]:
                    #print(str(source_curr) + " END : " + str(dest_curr))
                    print('Found arbitrage: {0} --> {1}'.format(currency_tuple[source_curr], currency_tuple[dest_curr]))
            
        
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        arbitrage(currencies, rates)
```

**output :** Found arbitrage: FXRP --> YFLR

However - That does not actually give Arbitage.

I was looking for a result that would give every possibilitly to arbitrage regardless of "sequence size"

Hoped Result example :
'xUSD --> FXRP --> FLTC --> xUSD

I also looked at :
[How to use Python and Pandas to find bests opportunities in triangular arbitrage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190728/how-to-use-python-and-pandas-to-find-bests-opportunities-in-triangular-arbitrage) and despite this code looking like it got fixed in the end, it doesn’t explain the arbitrage journey.

So I was wondering if anyone has examples of python arbitrage calculation – rather than an entire framework connection to all the crypto exchanges etc.

Cheers